# MySQL - Computing the AVG(DISTINCT) of a relation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Column B of a relation has the following list of values in the five rows of the table:
3, NULL, 2, 3, 5

Which of the following is the correct value of AVG(DISTINCT B)?

I have tried creating a relational table here with the specified rows and then executed AVG(DISTINCT A): http://ideone.com/3ItE01

```
 CREATE TABLE A(a int(8), b int(8), c int(8), d int(8), e int(8));
 INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, NULL, 2, 3, 5);
 INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, NULL, 2, 3, 5);
 INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, NULL, 2, 3, 5);
 INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, NULL, 2, 3, 5);
 INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, NULL, 2, 3, 5);
```

But my SQL Query of "AVG(DISTINCT A)" is not valid. I am new to SQL and looking for documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Insert values with query

```
insert  into `test`(`id`,`value`) values (1,'3'),(2,'2'),(3,'3'),(4,NULL),(5,'5');
```

now use query

```
SELECT AVG( DISTINCT test.value)FROM test
```

to calculate the average you will get the result `3.3333333333333335`